# RecyclerView scroll up issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am getting an error whenever i try to scroll up after scrolling down in my list view

here's my main code where the Recyclerview is being initialized :

```
public class MovieListActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnMovieListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MovieListActivity";
    private MovieListViewModel mMovieListViewModel;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MovieRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    private SearchView searchView;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list);

      mMovieListViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
      mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
     initRecyclerView();
      subscribeObserver();
     initSearchview();

     if(!mMovieListViewModel.isViewingMovie()){
         displayCategory();
     }
     setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }



    private void subscribeObserver(){
        mMovieListViewModel.getMovieList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Movie> movies) {
           if(movies!=null){
             //  Testing.printRecipes(movies,"onPrint");
               mAdapter.setMovies(movies);
           }
            }
        });
    }



     private void initRecyclerView(){
        mAdapter= new MovieRecyclerAdapter(this);
         VerticalSpacingItemDecorator verticalSpacingItemDecorator= new VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(30);
         mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(verticalSpacingItemDecorator);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if(! mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
                    mMovieListViewModel.searchNextPage(Constant.API_KEY);
                }
            }
        });

     }

     private void initSearchview() {

       searchView=findViewById(R.id.search_view);
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
             mAdapter.displayLoading();
             mMovieListViewModel.searchMovieApi(Constant.API_KEY,query,1);
             mMovieListViewModel.setIsPerformingQuery(false);
             searchView.clearFocus();
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             return false;
         }
     });
     }

    @Override
    public void onMovieClick(int position) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MovieActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("movie",mAdapter.getSelectedMovie(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCategoryClick(String category) {
    mAdapter.displayLoading();
    mMovieListViewModel.searchMovieApi(Constant.API_KEY,category,1);
    searchView.clearFocus();
}

private void displayCategory(){
    mMovieListViewModel.setIsViewingMovie(false);
    mAdapter.displaySearchCategory();
}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
   if(mMovieListViewModel.onBackPressed()){
        super.onBackPressed();}
   else {displayCategory();}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.movie_search_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_categories){
        displayCategory();
       
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

when i do the scrolling up movement i get this error :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDistance(Landroid/widget/EdgeEffect;)F in class Landroidx/core/widget/EdgeEffectCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.tvguide-1/base.apk)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.stopGlowAnimations(RecyclerView.java:3534)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2206)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2606)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2266)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1745)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2834) ......etc

this the adapter class:

```
    public class MovieRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
 private static final int MOVIE_TYPE=1;
 private static final int LOADING_TYPE=2;
 private static final int CATEGORY_TYPE=3;

    private List<Movie> mMovies;
   private OnMovieListener onMovieListener;

    public MovieRecyclerAdapter( OnMovieListener onMovieListener) {
        this.onMovieListener = onMovieListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=null;

        switch (viewType){
            case MOVIE_TYPE :
                view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item,parent,false);

                return new MovieViewHolder(view,onMovieListener);

            case LOADING_TYPE :
                view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.loading_movie_item,parent,false);

                return new LoadingViewHolder(view);

            case CATEGORY_TYPE:
                view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_list_category,parent,false);

                return new CategoryViewHolder(view,onMovieListener);

            default:
                view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item,parent,false);

                return new MovieViewHolder(view,onMovieListener);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int itemViewType=getItemViewType(position);

        if(itemViewType==CATEGORY_TYPE){
            RequestOptions requestOptions= new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

            Uri path=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.tvguide/drawable/"+ mMovies.get(position).getPoster_path());
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                    .load(path)
                    .into(((CategoryViewHolder)holder).categoryImage);
            ((CategoryViewHolder)holder).categoryTitle.setText(mMovies.get(position).getTitle());

          //  Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: poster path "+mMovies.get(position).getPosterPath());

        }

       else   if(itemViewType==MOVIE_TYPE){

            RequestOptions requestOptions= new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);


            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                    .load(Constant.IMAGE_BASE_URL+mMovies.get(position).getPoster_path())

                    .into(((MovieViewHolder)holder).image);


            ((MovieViewHolder)holder).title.setText(mMovies.get(position).getTitle());
            ((MovieViewHolder)holder).release_date.setText(mMovies.get(position).getRelease_date());
            ((MovieViewHolder)holder).vote_average.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(mMovies.get(position).getVote_average())));

        }

    }
```

and here are the views:

the movielist view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MovieListActivity">
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:id="@+id/search_view"
      app:queryHint="SpiderMan...."/>
 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the listitem view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/movie_image_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/movie_image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/movie_title_text_size"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_title"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="100">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="90"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/release_date_text_size"
                        android:id="@+id/release_date"
                        android:gravity="start"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/release_date_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"
                        android:id="@+id/vote_average"
                        android:gravity="center"/>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and the last part the buidle.gradel module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' }
        }}

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tvguide"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def appcompat_version = "1.3.1"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
    // For loading and tinting drawables on older versions of the platform
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.0"
    // def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"


}
```

Comment: make sure that the no heavy size images load in recyclerview

Comment: if you are using heavy size image then convert your image into webp format.Android studio support webp format. just right click on resource file and click on webp convert\

Comment: i still got the same error